# Login Page Logo and Site Icon gives 404 in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, craft-pro

I have update the craft version from 3.0.2 to 3.0.3.1, after that Login Page Logo and Site Icon gives 404 path error. I have checked file permissions also but it is not creating link in cpresources folder while it is showing url in frontend. In local its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed for the next release. Only affects environments where the web server is not sending missing resource requests (like `/cpresources/XXXXXX/logo.svg`) to `index.php`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you please explain in brief about your sentence "Only affects environments.." .